# Problems with `\declaretheoremstyle` `\headformat`

Tags: boxes, amsthm, thmtools

I'm trying to change the `headformat` option in `declaretheoremstyle`, but I'm getting errors, even when copying the code in `thmtools` that allows `\headformat=margin`. Here's my preamble:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheoremstyle[
    headformat=\makebox[0pt][r]{\NUMBER\ }\NAME\NOTE,
    notefont=\bfseries, 
    notebraces={}{},
]{mystyle}

\theoremstyle{mystyle}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
```

But when I try to build, I get an error pointint to `headformat=` and the output goes to the default:

[image]

Any ideas why `\makebox` isn't working when following `\headformat=`?

Alternatively, if I adjust my preamble to

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheoremstyle[
    headformat=\makebox[0pt][r]{\NUMBER\ }\NAME\NOTE,
    notefont=\bfseries, 
    notebraces={}{},
]{mystyle}

\theoremstyle{mystyle}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
```

I get

[image]

Why is there that unwanted space before the `\NOTE` text?

Comment: Mmm… What exactly is alternating?

Comment: Please provide code we can use to reproduce the problem. Please specify *which* error you get. Also, why do you expect that to work because `headformat=margin` works? That seems like it is referencing a defined format, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `]` after `0pt` is mistaken for the closing bracket of the optional argument to `\declaretheoremstyle`. Enclose the value for `headformat` in braces.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example
\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheoremstyle[
    headformat={\makebox[0pt][r]{\NUMBER\ }\NAME\NOTE},
    notefont=\bfseries, 
    notebraces={}{},
]{mystyle}

\theoremstyle{mystyle}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{thm}
Whatever
\end{thm}

\begin{thm}[Oops]
Whatever
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

[image]